# Use existing control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

I have a DLL which I need to use in an MVC application.  I have added the `namespace` to the `web.config` file, but this doesn't work when I try to use the control in a `View`.  I can't do:

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="fjx" Namespace="com.flajaxian" Assembly="com.flajaxian.FileUploader" %>`

because MVC Views won't allow this.  Any ideas on how I can use an existing control in an MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import namespaces in razor views razor like this:

```
@using MyNamespace;
```

or when using the classic aspx engine:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

Using the flajaxian asp.net webforms controls in MVC won't work though. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444660/net-mvc-how-to-use-net-controls-with-mvc) for details and alternatives.

Comment: here is the page with the control on http://www.flajaxian.com/flajaxian.com/docs/default.aspx.  I've tried to add the `using` statement, but that doesn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Neil: You won't be able to use regular ASP.Net controls in MVC. See this post for details and alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444660/net-mvc-how-to-use-net-controls-with-mvc